# SQL Getting Top 2 Results for each individual column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'Cashup_Till' that records all data on what a particular till has recorded in a venue for a given day, each venue has multiple tills all with a designated number 'Till_No'. I need to get the previous 2 days entries for each till number. For each till Individually I can do this...

```
SELECT TOP 2 T.* FROM CashUp_Till T 
WHERE T.Till_No = (Enter Till Number Here)
ORDER BY T.Till_Id DESC
```

Some venues have 20-30 tills so Ideally I need to do all the tills in one call. I can pass in a user defined table type of till numbers, then select them in a subquery, but that's as far as my SQL knowledge takes me, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Which columns represents the venue?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've not included the venue/day column in the example just for simplicity, there's is a Site_Day_Id that I include in the where clause

Comment: What do you mean by previous two days?  Is there more than one record per day?  What if the latest day doesn't have a record?

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is a Site_Day_Id Column in the table, but I didn't think it was necessary to include in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM (SELECT T.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Till_No ORDER BY Till_Id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM CashUp_Till T 
     ) T
WHERE seqnum <= 2;
```

This assumes that there is one record per day, which I believe is suggested by the question.

If you have a separate table of tills, then:

```
select ct.*
from t cross apply
     (select top 2 ct.*
      from cashup_till ct
      where ct.till_no = t.till_no
      order by till_id desc
     ) ct;
```

Comment: Yes you are right to assume, each till only has one entry per day - I'll give this a whirl, thanks